# View xlsx file in browser : php

Tags: php, xlsx

I want to view my xlsx file that is store in Mysql database as binary in the browser without downloading it. I tried modifying headers, but still not being able to view data in the browser.

```
$sql = "SELECT excel_content FROM excel_test WHERE id ='".$id."'";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(); 
$content = $stmt->fetchAll();
$excelcontent= $content['0']['excel_content'];
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
echo $excelcontent;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Browser simply can't render xlsx natively.

Comment: did you try 1. printing `$excelcontent= $content['0']['excel_content'];` on console and does it print anything? 2. Did you try `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1 
     Content-transfer-encoding: base64
`

Comment: Most browsers don't understand how to show an xlsx, unless they have a plugin. It's not your code's fault

Comment: 1. Yes, I do get binary data in ```$excelcontent```, if I save this binary data as xlsx file, the file opens up too. 2. I did try ```Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1       Content-transfer-encoding: base64 ``` and it still doesnt work too. @vish

Comment: @vish I don't understand why you think that would help? The browser isn't going to know how to turn that into an Excel display.

Comment: Hello @ADyson, just wanted to confirm we are getting something in the buffer.